# Connecting to mysql database from a remote host

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm a bit confused, all documentation and guides around this topic show the following commands:

```
mysql --host=remote_server --user=myname --password=password mydb
```

Does that mean I have to install mysql on the remote host too? (from which I'm connecting)

The thing is, I'm running Wordpress &NGINX on docker on one server, and MariaDB on another, so I just want to test the connection.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is the MySQL *client*. The server app is the part that runs the SQL, the client is the one that allows you to type commands and run SQL.

The command you've shown is to connect to a remote *server* so you will need the *client* software on the machine you want to access it from. Whether that is the docker host with your WordPress system, or your desktop machine is not clear from your question.

Clients which are connecting via another application do not need the client or server applications, only the libraries/drivers. There are multiple ones available, but as you're running WordPress PHP has connectivity built in.